# Difference between using requests.get() and requests.session().get()?

Tags: python, python-requests

Sometimes I see people invoke web API using requests.Session object:

```
client = requests.session()
resp = client.get(url='...')
```

But sometimes they don't:

```
resp = requests.get(url='...')
```

Can somebody explain when should we use `Session` and when we don't need them?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Under the hood, `requests.get()` creates a new `Session` object for each request made.

By creating a session object up front, you get to *reuse* the session; this lets you persist cookies, for example, and lets you re-use settings to be used for all connections such as headers and query parameters. To top this all off, sessions let you take advantage of connection pooling; reusing connections to the same host.

See the [*Sessions* documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects):

> The Session object allows you to persist certain parameters across requests. It also persists cookies across all requests made from the Session instance, and will use urllib3‘s connection pooling. So if you’re making several requests to the same host, the underlying TCP connection will be reused, which can result in a significant performance increase (see [HTTP persistent connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection)).

Comment: So if my HTTP request is a one-time task, there will be no difference between these two approaches, right?

Comment: @FredPym: exactly. As soon as you make multiple connections to the same host, reusing the session is a good idea.

Comment: @MartijnPieters requests.get does not support Adapter for retry logic but session does. do you suggest using session for one-time request if retry is needed by using httpadapter

Comment: @SHIVAMJINDAL Yes,  using a transport adapter requires that you create a dedicated Session instance.

Answer (score 1):

To quote the [documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/)

> The Session object allows you to persist certain parameters across requests. It also persists cookies across all requests made from the Session instance.