# Do we need to close session explicitly in django request?

Tags: django, session

Let's say, we have class

```
class Pipe(object):
    def __init__(self, imp_url=IAMPORT_API_URL):
        requests_session = requests.Session()
        requests_adapters = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_retries=3)
        requests_session.mount('https://', requests_adapters)
        self.requests_session = requests_session

    def get(self, url, payload=None)
        return self.requests_session.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload)
```

views.py

```
class RequestAPIView(APIView):
    def put(self, request):
        pipe = Pipe()
        pipe.get(...)
        pipe.get(...)
        ....
```

After call RequestAPIView, Do we need to close self.session explicitly in pipe object?
Or after RequestAPIView done, Does the self.session will be closed automatically?

Comment: Your code runs two get requests on initialisation of your app, they are triggered in the RequestAPIView class body. Is this supposed to be the case? What is the purpose of the session?

Comment: I fixed code, there was a mistake.Without session, I guess when code run get request , It will makes each session automatically So it makes overhead. So I want to reduce it that is why I am using.

Comment: Under the hood, requests.get() creates a new Session object for each request made.

By creating a session object up front, you get to reuse the session; this lets you persist cookies, for example, and lets you re-use settings to be used for all connections such as headers and query parameters. To top this all off, sessions let you take advantage of connection pooling; reusing connections to the same host.
[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32986228/difference-between-using-requests-get-and-requests-session-get)

Comment: No, you don't need to explicitly close the session. You open one per every PUT request. so after the request is done the session will be discarded

Comment: Thanks, Is there way to check whether session is closed?